# How synchronize two disks (or folders) using symbolic (or hard) links (like rsync)?

Tags: shell-script, utilities, symlink, programming, synchronization

I'm searching a **tool** or a **shell script** or **another program** to synchronize two or more folders or disks.

But it differs of rsync tool, because, I don't want to duplicate the missing file, but do a symbolic link of it in the other folder, for example:

If in folder ***A*** we have the files ***a*** and ***b*** and other folder ***c*** with a file ***d***:

> A
>
> > a
> >
> > b
> >
> > c
> >
> > > d

And in folder ***B*** we have the file ***1*** and a folder ***2*** with a file ***3***:

> B
>
> > 1
> >
> > 2
> >
> > > 3

I would like program, for example, *ssync* (symbolic synchronize, just a invention name), called by a command, for example, ***ssync /A /B*** to change these folders like showed below:

> A
>
> > a
> >
> > b
> >
> > c
> >
> > > d
> >
> > 1 (ln -s)
> >
> > 2 (ln -s)
> >
> > > 3 (ln -s)

and

> B
>
> > 1
> >
> > 2
> >
> > > 3
> >
> > a (ln -s)
> >
> > b (ln -s)
> >
> > c (ln -s)
> >
> > > d (ln -s)

where ***ln -s*** indicates that in this folder was created a symbolic link to this corresponding file, for example, ***a (ln -s)*** indicates the command ***ln -s /A/a /B/a*** was used.

I will appreciate so much if someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into `rsnapshot`, which creates _hard links_?  I won't be using symlinks to synchronize anything.  Access/modification times are hard to duplicate with symlinks.  Attempts to change the atime of a symlink often result in "Permission denied" errors, even if you own the symlink.

Comment: Hard links it's really a good idea. But do you have a ideia to do this with to two folders (with another folders in), synchronizing all files creating hard links?
I am interesting in this *rsnapshot* package but it isn't familiar to me, so if you write a command explaining your idea I would like so much. Thanks!

Comment: I was reading about the hard links in rsnapshot, but looks like it create and uses a hard link only if a file isn't modificated...looks like I can't create a hard link instead copy the file (in the first running synchronization), but I'd would like create the hard link...never the entire file... could I do this with this rsnapshot or another tool?

Comment: rsnapshot (rsnapshot.org) is not standard, but it builds on top of rsync.  I've re-engineered it in Python to include in an install program to handle months of backups with minimal space.  I sync entire trees, not just a single directory.

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was a mode to sync two directory trees instead of just making multiple revisions of the first tree.  I've been using my own version for a few years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
srcdir="$1"
dstdir="$2"
if [ -h "$srcdir" ]; then
    val=`readlink "$srcdir"`
    if [ ! -h "$dstdir" ]; then
        rm -rf "$dstdir"
    fi
    ln -s "$val" "$dstdir"
elif [ -d "$srcdir" ]; then
    if [ ! -d "$dstdir" ]; then
        rm -rf "$dstdir"
    fi
    mkdir "$dstdir"
    for i in `ls -1A "$srcdir"`; do
        $0 "$srcdir/$i" "$dstdir/$i"
    done
    touch -a -r "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
    touch -m -r "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
else
    if [ ! -f "$dstdir" ]; then
        rm -rf "$dstdir"
    fi
    ln "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
fi
```

This doesn't handle "special" files like block devices, named pipes, sockets, etc..

Comment: thx a lot about your script. I will investigate it. Really thx about your time.

Comment: Thx very very much... I need learn a bit more to understood all your code but it works perfectly. Thx. Unfortunally I didn't have 100 points or more to give you...or vote up +10 in your answer...I think this can help a lot of people. For example...if you want creta a folder with links to all files do you have in all partitions you have...to movies, texts, pdfs, musics, etc.